# How to find a nearest higher number from a specific set of numbers :javascript

Tags: javascript, object, numbers

I have a set of numbers & my requirements is to find same or nearest higher number to a specific variable 
set/object  of numbers

```
var person = {
    A:107,
    B:112,
    C:117,
    D:127,
    E:132,
    F:140,
    G:117,
    H:127,
    I:132,
    J:132,
    K:140,
    L:147,
    M:117,
    N:127,
    O:132
};
```

I need to find a nearest higher number to vaiable x
eg1- if

```
x = 116;
```

then  nearest higher number to x from number set is 117, which repeat at C, G, M
so I need to find out C, G, M programatically with javascript

eg2-

```
x= 127
```

then  same number  to x from number set repeat at D,H,N
so I need to find out D,H,N programatically with javascript

Thanks for Help

Comment: what did you try solving this issue>

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: actually I have to create a program for  wearable cloth size calculator from size chart & this is my one of step of program

Comment: So, um, a for..in loop to iterate through the values, with a variable to keep track of the current nearest value? You haven't tried writing any code yet?

Comment: I guess what @RajaprabhuAravindasamy is asking is if you tried doing something yourself first or just went straight to asking.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *reduce* to find the lowest difference and collect the keys with that value. If a lower difference is found, the keys array is replaced with the new set of lower keys, e.g.

```js
function getNextHighest(obj, value) {
  var diff = Infinity;
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(acc, key) {
    var d = obj[key] - value; 
    if (d > 0 && d < diff) {
   diff = d;
   acc = [key];
 } else if (d == diff) {
   acc.push(key)
 }
 return acc;
  }, [])
}

var person = {A:107,B:112,C:117,D:127,E:132,F:140,G:117,
              H:127,I:132,J:132,K:140,L:147,M:117,N:127,O:132
             };

document.write(getNextHighest(person, 116));
document.write('<br>' + getNextHighest(person, 140));
```

Comment: thanks it's work perfectly sorry there is little tweak which I forget to mention in question, in need set of nearest higher number to x from number.

Comment: @Dinesh—change `d > 0` to `d >= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Note, if you just want keys, you can replace `result[k] = obj[k];` to `result.push(k)` and make result an array.

```js
var person = {A:107,B:112,C:117,D:127,E:132,F:140,G:117,H:127,I:132,J:132,K:140,L:147,M:117,N:127,O:132};

function searchNearestNum(obj, x){
  var value = null;
  var result = {};
  
  Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a,b){
   return obj[a]>obj[b]?1:(obj[a]<obj[b])?-1:0
  }).forEach(function(k){
    if(!value && obj[k]>x){
      value = obj[k];
      result[k] = obj[k];
    }
    else if(obj[k] === value){
      result[k] = obj[k];
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}

function getList(){
  var searchValue = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  if(searchValue && !isNaN(searchValue)){
    searchValue = parseInt(searchValue);
    print(searchNearestNum(person, searchValue));
  }
}

function print(obj){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj,0,4) + "</pre>";
}
```

```html
<input id="txt"/>
<button onclick="getList()">get list</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally edited to satisfy my commenters =)

```
var x = 116;

var max = x;

for (var key in person) {
  if(person[key]>max){
    max = person[key];
  }
}

function nextMax(ar, k, m) {
    var dif = m; //Some high number
    var rkey = null;
    for (var key in ar) {
        var check = ar[key]-k;
        if(check<dif && check > 0){
          dif = check;
          rkey = key;
        }
    }
    return(rkey);
}

var keys = [];
var values = [];
for(var ckey; ckey = nextMax(person, x, max); ){
    if(ckey == null){
    break;
  }
  keys.push(ckey);
  values.push(person[ckey]);
  x = person[ckey];
}

console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

check it working: https://jsfiddle.net/Aschab/q65wes0a/2/

Comment: not working for val 140

Comment: Amulya Kashyap. I just tested for 140, it gives me  K:140. Thats as close as it gets.

Comment: still it's giving 140 only and answer should be 147

Comment: You were right. I missread the problem. I thought it was nearest, and its Nearest Higher. I edited it for it to correctly work.

Comment: This just returns the next highest value, not an array of all keys with the next highest value.

Comment: Also relies on the magic `dif` number and won't take negatives into account.

Comment: array of keys and value returned. No longer relies on magic dif. I'm tend to be more practical than I should on my first attempt

Answer (score 0):

## Approach 1

Try this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/30zjzja7/3/) of a **very simple** algorithm

**First step** -> Push the values in an array as [key, value, **difference between value and search**]

```
var personArray = [];
for ( var key in person )
{
  if ( ( person[key] - 116 ) > 0 )
  {
     personArray.push([key, person[key], person[key] - 116  ]);
  }
}
```

**Final Step** -> Sort it by the **difference value**

```
personArray.sort( function(a,b){return a[2]-b[2]} );
console.log( personArray[0][1] );
```

## Approach 2

To make it even more simpler, keep the handle of lowest difference

```
var personArray = [];
var lowestDifference = 0;
var nearestHigherValue = 0;
for ( var key in person )
{
  var difference = person[key] - 116;
  if ( difference > 0 && lowestDifference < difference )
  {
     lowestDifference = difference;
     nearestHigherValue = person[key] ;
  }
}
console.log("nearest higher value is " + nearestHigherValue );
```

Comment: I guess you can sort `keys` based on value, instead of pushing key and value in array and sort it and then search.

Comment: @Rajesh I agree, I don't think adding a key to the array is necessary.

Comment: I meant, not creating array in the first place. You can check my answer. Though took idea of sorting from your answer.

Comment: @Rajesh that will be necessary otherwise how will you know which `difference value` is mapped to which `value`?

Comment: I meant, manually creating `personArray`. You can use `Object.keys().sort()`.

Comment: @Rajesh Nope! how would sorting by keys help?  And how does that warrent a downvote?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a,b){
   return obj[a]>obj[b]?1:(obj[a]<obj[b])?-1:0
  })`.

Comment: @Rajesh `Object.keys(obj)` will give you only keys and then on top of that you would do a sort on the value also (since it doesn't have the values anymore, it only has keys)? will it even work?

Comment: Please refer to my answer. I have already in implemented this and tried to make answer interactive.

Comment: @Rajesh So you downvoted because the answer is not same as your answer?

Comment: No. I'm not the downvoter. I have that much sense to appreciate any idea that adds value.

Comment: it's, for me, a problem with sorting for just getting some values at top or bottom of the array. big O in this case is at best case O(n), in a more worst case O(n^2), depending on the alogrithm. additionally you have already O(n) for building the array for sorting.

Comment: @NinaScholz can you please check now? It has been made even more simpler with no sorting or array creation.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this should work** :

```
var resultObject = [];

function search(x, person){
    for (var i=0; i < person.length; i++) {
        if ((person[i].name === x) || (person[i].name === (x+i))) {
            return person[i];
        }
    }
}

var result = search(x, person);
resultObject.push(result);
var x = resultObject.length;
while(x >0){
   console.log(x+"\n");x--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
function findNearestNumbers(x, person) {
  var results = [];
  var currentClosest;

  // Difference function measures the difference
  // between two numbers
  var diff = function(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a - b);
  }

  // Loop through each number on the person
  for(var i in person) {

    // We don't even need to do the diff if x is greater
    // than the current number
    if(x > p[i]) {
      continue;
    }

    // Calculate the differnce between the current
    // Number and the supplied 'x' value
    var d = diff(x, person[i]);

    // We want the highest number, not a matching number.
    if(diff === 0) {
       continue;
    }

    if(!currentClosest || d < currentClosest) {

      // If it's the closest number so far, create
      // a new array to store the results, with this key as
      // the first element
      results = [i];
      currentClosest = d;
    }
    else if(currentClosest === d) {

      // If this is number is the same as the closest number
      // then add this key to the results array
      results.push(i);
    }
  }

  return results;
}
```

Try the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/y4nu3t0d/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `for..in` loop,  `Object.keys()`, `Array.prototype.map()`,  `Array.prototype.reduce()` to store values of `person` as property keys of new object. If property does not exist add property of `person`, else concatenate property of `person` at created object; filter properties by comparing as numbers; return concatenated string containing properties of original object where filtered number is greater than input parameter number

```js
var person = {
  A: 107, B: 112, C: 117, D: 127, E: 132,
  F: 140, G: 117, H: 127, I: 132, J: 132,
  K: 140, L: 147, M: 117, N: 127, O: 132
};

var res = function(n) {
  var data = {};
  for (var prop in person) data[person[prop]] = (data[person[prop]] || "") + prop;
  return data[Object.keys(data).map(Number).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a > n ? a : b
  })];
}

document.body.textContent = res(116) + "\n" + res(140)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a series of `sort` and `filter` on the object:

```
var person = {
  A: 107,
  B: 112,
  C: 117,
  D: 127,
  E: 132,
  F: 140,
  G: 117,
  H: 127,
  I: 132,
  J: 132,
  K: 140,
  L: 147,
  M: 117,
  N: 127,
  O: 132
};

var myNum = 117;

var nearest = Object.keys(person)
.sort(function(item1, item2) {
    if (person[item1] > person[item2]) {return 1};
    if (person[item1] < person[item2]) {return -1};
   return 0;
}).filter(function(item) {
  return person[item] >= myNum;
}).filter(function(item, index, list){
  return person[list[0]] == person[item];
});

console.log(nearest) // will print ["C","M","G"]
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnLaq86f/) for a complete example.

Comment: The sort function could be `return person[item1] - person[item2]` and there should only be a need for one *filter*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thi is a straight forward approach with an `Array#forEach` loop and a variable for keeping the delta and one for the keys.

```js
function nearestHigher(object, v) {
    var delta = -1,
        keys = [];
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        var d = object[k] - v;
        if (d > 0) {
            if (!~delta || d < delta) {
                delta = d;
                keys = [k];
                return;
            }
            d === delta && keys.push(k);
        }
    });
    return keys;
}

var person = { A: 107, B: 112, C: 117, D: 127, E: 132, F: 140, G: 117, H: 127, I: 132, J: 132, K: 140, L: 147, M: 117, N: 127, O: 132 };

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(nearestHigher(person, 116), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(nearestHigher(person, 132), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(nearestHigher(person, 140), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: OP is looking for next greater number. So in case of 132, it should be 140 and in case of 140, it should be 147 (L)

Comment: @Rajesh, thank you for pointing me out to this detail, please see edit.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function getNearest(x){
   var keys=[];
   for(var key in person){
     if(person[key]==x+1)
        keys.push(key)
   }
   return keys;
}
getNearest(116)
```

Comment: 140?....he wanted only the nearest higher number of X not all the higher number of X

Comment: Try your code with `140`: `getNearest(140)`. It doesn't give the correct result.

Comment: Exactly dude, _NEAREST_ not just plus 1. what if `person = {a:116:b:118}`?