# How to find a same or nearest higher number from a specific set of numbers :javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a set of numbers & my requirements is to find same or nearest higher number to a specific variable set/object of numbers

```
var person = {
    A:107,
    B:112,
    C:117,
    D:127,
    E:132,
    F:140,
    G:117,
    H:127,
    I:132,
    J:132,
    K:140,
    L:147,
    M:117,
    N:127,
    O:132
};
```

I need to find a nearest higher number to vaiable x
eg1- if

```
x = 116;
```

then nearest higher number to x from number set is 117, which repeat at C, G, M so I need to find out C, G, M programatically with javascript

eg2-

```
x= 127
```

then same number to x from number set repeat at D,H,N so I need to find out D,H,N programatically with javascript

Thanks for Help

tried code

```js
function getNextHighest(obj, value) {
  var diff = Infinity;
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(acc, key) {
    var d = obj[key] - value; 
    if (d > 0 && d < diff) {
   diff = d;
   acc = [key];
 } else if (d == diff) {
   acc.push(key)
 }
 return acc;
  }, [])
}

var person = {A:107,B:112,C:117,D:127,E:132,F:140,G:117,
              H:127,I:132,J:132,K:140,L:147,M:117,N:127,O:132
             };

document.write(getNextHighest(person, 116));
document.write('<br>' + getNextHighest(person, 127));
```

but problem is with this code I am getting only next highest number, it ignore same number 
eg- in case of 127 result should be D, H, N but program output is E,I,J,O
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837589/how-to-find-a-nearest-higher-number-from-a-specific-set-of-numbers-javascript You have asked it already. So you planned to not to write anything on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your line

```
if (d > 0 && d < diff) {
```

to

```
if (d >= 0 && d < diff) {
```

so it includes the numbers that are equal as well.